# What guidelines should be followed for policies and procedures?

Tags: policy, procedure

Our company, being rather small, doesn't have much in the way of policies and procedures for good development.  When I first started, I developed some, but we now need to update these in a more formal manner.  Since I don't have much experience in writing policies (I've written plenty of instruction sets, so I'm not as worried about the procedures, though still thoughtful), I want to ask the community for tips and advice on writing good policies and procedures for software development.  Thanks.

Comment: What language?  What type of software?

Comment: We're presently using a combination of Delphi and C# with the intention of moving entirely to C#.  Software is a custom database reporting/analysis package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of policies depend of your programming languages, but :

1. Write naming rules to uniforme the code of your team
2. Write general coding rules like [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle
3. For customers and bugs management, take a look at [ITIL](http://www.itil.org/en/vomkennen/itil/index.php)
4. For delay and tasks management, I recommand [Scrum](http://www.scrumalliance.org/) method
5. Write a chapter about design patterns ([design pattern head first](http://://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/))
6. If you want more formal procedures, have a look at [ISO 90003](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=35867)

Some other books can help you like [Code complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

Answer (score 2):

My humble opinion... don't overdo it :) A small team needs a shared understanding and vision of how things work. While policies serve communications in large companies, they tend to devolve into power struggles with smaller groups. I found traditions grown out of experience more useful than procedures stated ahead of time.

That said, software dev establishments need some systems for source control, issue tracking, and a place for dropping documentation. Clarity around how decisions are made is immensely useful, as is an understanding of what a project looks like.

Avoid fights on whether there has to be a space character before the semicolon like the plague, and make sure to leave enough room for fun...